# List of RBAC permissions for all Azure Resources

Tags: azure, user-permissions, rbac

Are there APIs to list all the RBAC permissions available for Azure Resources ?

I am trying to get the list in order to identify the privileged custom roles and effective permissions of users in the Subscription.
I am looking for the list of 1.actions 2.notActions  3.dataActions 4.notDataActions properties of Permissions for all Azure resources.

Please let me know in case you have come across any Azure apis that can do this.Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The [method](https://cmatskas.com/list-all-rbac-permissions-for-all-resources-in-azure/) with Powershell uses `foreach` to iterate through each resources and retrieve the RBAC permissions. There is no direct method to list of RBAC permissions for all Azure Resources with Azure API.

As a workaround, you need to get all resources in subscription, then loop to get the permissions in each resource.

Follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureresourcegraph/resourcegraph(2019-04-01)/resources/resources) to get all resources:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.ResourceGraph/resources?api-version=2019-04-01
```

Follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-rbac-roleassignment-list?view=graph-rest-1.0) to get the permissions:

```
GET /deviceManagement/roleDefinitions/{roleDefinitionId}/roleAssignments
```

Comment: I believe OP is requesting a full list of possible actions (or notActions, ...) that are available for certain resources. You are confusing this with a list of roleAssignments, which is not the same. I have the same question as OP btw.

- A *role definition* consists of a set of allowed actions. We are looking for a list of the possible actions.
- A *role assignment* links a *role definition* to a certain principal (user, group,...) in a certain scope (resource group, subscription, ...)

Comment: There is a list of the built-in role definitions [online here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles), but it contains wildcards in the allowed actions and therefore does not provide a full clear list of all possible actions.